# out of range C++ error unit testing vector routine

Tags: c++, vector

I am unit testing this C++ routine, using Visual Studio C++ test framework. Given how the vector `graph` is populated (shown below), it should have 14 rows ( this is verified in another unit test ) and 4 columns. So how is it going beyond its bounds? My code shouldn't produce any values of x1 or x2 which don't meet one of the inequalities, but just incase I added an `else if (i == graph.size() - 1) { y1 = 1; y2 = 1; }`clause, to break the `while` loop conditions, but the error is still thrown. What have I done wrong?

```
float averageGradient(int x1, int x2) {
    int i = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0;
    while (y1 == 0 || y2 == 0) {                           //if both y values haven't been solved then keep trying
        if (x1 >= graph[i][0] && x1 < graph[i][1]) {       // if x1 lies in the first straight line segment
            y1 = (graph[i][2] * x1) + graph[i][3];         // then calculate it's y value (y1)
        }
        else if (x2 >= graph[i][0] && x2 < graph[i][1]) {  //try the same thing for x2
            y2 = (graph[i][2] * x2) + graph[i][3];         //calculate its y value (y2)
        }
        else { i++; }                                      //otherwise incriment i to check the next straight line segment
    }
    float m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
    return m;
};
```

> Result StackTrace: 
>   at std::vector >,std::allocator > > >::operator in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector:line 1240
>       at averageGradient() in c:\users\documents\history testing\history testing 2\historytesting.h:line 74
>       at UnitTest1::MyTests::Average_Gradient() in c:\users\documents\history testing\unittest1\unittest1.cpp:line 42
>   Result Message: Invalid parameter detected in function std::vector >,class std::allocator > > >::operator [], c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector line 1233. Expression: "out of range"

the vector graph is populated like this:

```
vector< vector<float> > history;
vector<float> values;
vector< vector<float> > graph;

void drawGraph() {
    float m, c, j, x1, x2;
    graph.clear();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < history.size() - 1) {
        j = i + 1;
        x1 = history[i][0];
        x2 = history[j][0];
        m = history[j][3] / history[j][2];
        c = history[i][1] - m*x2;
        i++;
        values.push_back(x1);
        values.push_back(x2);
        values.push_back(m);
        values.push_back(c);
        graph.push_back(values);
        values.clear();
    }
};
```

## Unit Tests:

```
TEST_METHOD(Graph_Equations_Correct) {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    drawGraph();
    while (i < 14) {
        Assert::AreEqual(graph.at(i)[2], history.at(j)[4]);
        Assert::IsNotNull(&graph.at(i)[3]);
        i++; j++;
    }
    Assert::AreEqual(history.size()-1, graph.size());
}

TEST_METHOD(Average_Gradient) {
    int x1 = 683675;
    int x2 = x1 + 86400;
    int size = graph.size();
    float gradient = averageGradient(x1, x2);
    Assert::AreEqual(0, size);
    float answer = 0.0000895684639;
    //Assert::AreEqual(answer, gradient);
}
```

Both of these tests pass, but the first one shows that graph is populated with size 14, why for the second test does it now equal 0?

Comment: Please post [mcve], so that we can try your code ourselves. On the other note, did you try using debugger?

Comment: You should run this through a debugger so you can see what is happening or just print out your variable values when `i` exceeds the limit.

Comment: put this as the first part of your if tree not the last part.  if (i == graph.size() - 1) { y1 = 1; y2 = 1; }   by the time you execute it as an "else if" clause you have already potentially already accessed the graph[i] in the first or second if clause.   Or add it to the end of the while loop right after then i++.

Comment: @JonathanPotter It uses that because the `j` int is `i +1`

Comment: Or change your loop to `while (i < graph.size() && (y1 == 0 || y2 == 0))`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks! I am afraid that still throws the error though.

Comment: @AnonMail I am not very familiar with the VS2015 debugger, but usually the Autos window shows the value of all relevant variables when the code stopped, but it isn't showing anything? Is there a way I can integrate this into the unit test?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I have tried debugger, see my comment to Anon Mail

Comment: what line is 1240 inside the average gradient function?

Comment: @dboals not sure, that whole file is only 198 lines long ... ?

Comment: is line 74 within average gradient function?

Comment: @dboals line 1240 links to a line in vector standard header: return (*(this->_Myfirst() + _Pos));

Comment: @dboals Yes, line 74 is line 5 as I have written it in the question - the result if the first if is true

Comment: @dboals if I change the last `graph[i][3]` to `graph[i][2]`then I don't get the error thrown. Obviously, I get the test failed as it isn't the value I want to reference. But given the way graph is constructed, why would [3] be out of bounds?

Comment: Based on how you populated it, I don't see why that should make a difference.

Comment: The only thing I can see is the possibility that graph.size() is Zero and the bounds checking is off when this is the case. I would output the size of graph so I could see what it was at the time of failure.  Currently you don't have any protection if the sizeof graph is Zero.

Comment: @dboals You are right! Can't see why that would be?? I have added some info to the question

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Sorry, I have added the unit tests so you should now be able to replicate the problem.

Comment: You never call draw graph in the second test which is what populates the graph global.  I don't know much about the test bed you are using, but it may be that those are independent runs and the globals may not persist between runs.  I think you need to call draw graph in your second test.

Comment: @dboals This is something I wasn't sure about, but I tested it with the history vector and it seemed to persist between tests? Is there anywhere I can confirm what should happen in this situation?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Visual Studio testbed, so I can't help there, but my guess is that each test is an independent test.  If a test can be run independent of the others I would bet money they are each independent runs with the global variables reset between runs.